# How can I configure HTTP tunnel to configure my edx localhost to be accessible from the internet using ngrok?

Tags: apache, bitnami, ngrok, openedx, http-tunneling

I have the following question to use the linux package from openedx, where I want to configure an access tunnel using the ngrok tool (see documentation https://ngrok.com/docs#subdomain) so that through a subdomain based on ngrok it can be accessed from the internet, to know what I should modify.

I'm not clear what to do, I was reviewing the bitmami documentation of openedx and the ngrok documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/apache/#understand-virtual-host-configuration-files

https://ngrok.com/docs#subdomain

Thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to open the ports on the Firewall. In your case, you need to open the ports 80, 443 and 18010 (edX Studio) since you're using edX. [Here](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/linux-faq/#how-to-open-ports-for-remote-access), you can find more information about how to open ports for remote access.

Then, you can expose your server using ngrok as described below:

https://ngrok.com/docs#expose